# SSRS - Add a dropdown selection menu to a report

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ssrs-2012

Using Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2012.

I'm designing a main page for a group of reports I've developed. As a part of this page I want the user to be able to select from a number of available choices via a dropdown menu on the main page.

I have the Dataset within the report to collect the options I need to show the user. I have the parameter in the following report to accept their choice and alter the report accordingly.

There is nothing obvious within the Toolbox for inserting a Dropdown Menu.

As always, all help gratefully received.

M

Comment: Are you talking about parameter with drop-down menu?

Answer (score 1):

SSRS does not have a drop down menu in tool box. But any parameter linked to a Dataset can act as a dropdown. Once a parameter is added, go to Available Values and Select the option "Get Values from a Query" and provide the Dataset name, Value and Field.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Vijay, but as previously stated: "I have the Dataset within the report to collect the options I need to show the user. I have the parameter in the following report to accept their choice and alter the report accordingly." ...Your first sentence actually answered my question.

Comment: Thanks Matthew! Please mark it as an answer in that case.